Door Sweep on door with bowed hardwood floor
My bedroom door originally had a sweep screwed into it, but it was improperly installed and didn’t sit flush with the floor. To make things worse, a mouse chewed through part of it, so it needs replacing anyway. I removed and reinstalled the sweep to make it flush with the floor, but now it drags against the floor and creates resistance when opening or closing the door.
After taking measurements, I discovered that the floor is bowed—higher in the middle and lower on the sides. Because of this uneven surface, there’s no way to install the rubber door sweep so that it fully seals the gap along the entire door. The crack under the door is about 3/4" on the sides, which also seems to be allowing water bugs from the hallway to get into the apartment occasionally.
Does anyone have suggestions for how to solve this issue, considering the uneven floor, the need to block the cold air, and the potential pest problem?





Or use a brush sweep, e.g., htose at https://www.amazon.com/door-sweep-brush/s?k=door+sweep+brush . Bristles can be entirely flush (or bent over) with floor along full length, accommodating uneven floor and providing a good seal.

Consider something like this https://www.amazon.com/MAXTID-Stopper-Blocker-Stoppers-Adjustable/dp/B0B3DQNCCV/r?th=1

@mdfst13
So I live in a converted duplex, so the set up is a bit strange, my bedroom door goes into the shared, unheated hallway and is a wooden (interior) door.  The bedroom is heated by a mini split.  Below are some images with the descriptions on their respective pages.
https://ibb.co/KLHvBLZ
https://ibb.co/FqXRnm7
https://ibb.co/GQQWRbg
https://ibb.co/GFVtbPw

@isherwood Thanks!  I realize it's complicated to explain. here are some images with descriptions on their respective pages.  I'm really just looking for the easiest, cheapest fix but the existing doorsweep needs to be replaced anyway as it's damaged. I believe a brush style doorsweep could work but am unsure if that will be sufficient in terms of blocking any potential pests, or how easy it would be to trim?
https://ibb.co/KLHvBLZ
https://ibb.co/FqXRnm7
https://ibb.co/GQQWRbg
https://ibb.co/GFVtbPw

My initial suggestion of flexing the sweep might not work here. Even though we're dealing with rubber and fairly soft aluminum, this is a severe crown.
So... cut the rubber. Use a scribe technique to trace the floor with a suitable offset (the thickness of the largest gap). Use a sharp utility knife or scissor to slice to fit, then reposition the sweep to just touch the floor.
There's no good way to deal with drag during door operation. One alternative might be a bristle sweep.

That's not a bad idea, but the mind subconsciously doesn't expect a threshold indoors. It can be quite a trip hazard. Also, it's fairly challenging to do something like that without an array of woodworking tools.

Fair point. Write an answer.
